Extracting multiple-nested data from JSON using python
There are a couple of other questions on this topic that I saw but I haven't been able to work through the problem in this specific case even so.
In a json file, I am trying to get a certain integer from within nested lists, add another (fixed) integer to it, and write the modifed integer back out to the json file.
The integer I'm trying to modify is located within nested lists in the json, as follows:
[head]
-->'Creature List'
------->value [unnamed multiple entries in this list, each enclosed within a pair of curly brackets]
------------>'FactionID'
--------------------->'value:'
I want to modify that 'FactionID' 'value' integer (adding a fixed integer to it) and write the result back out to the json file.
There's a directory full of json files I'm trying to do this on.
My json looks like this (I've cut this down a lot but hopefully it's still parse-able):
`{
  "__data_type": "GIT ",
  "AreaProperties": {
    "__struct_id": 100,
    "type": "struct",
    "value": {      
    }
  },
  "Creature List": {
    "type": "list",
    "value": [
      {
        "__struct_id": 4,
        "Appearance_Type": {
          "type": "word",
          "value": 242
        },        
        "FactionID": {
          "type": "word",
          "value": 2
        },
      }
   }
}

I cannot access the subkeys within ['Creature List']['value']. There may be several different sub-lists within there. It looks to me like there's potentially a problem due to the sub-lists under ['Creature List']['value'] not having an integer or string name to identify the entries? But I am not going to be able to edit the json to fix this.
Here's the code I'm working with right now for testing purposes:
  for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.git.json'):
      file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename) 

      try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
          data = json.load(f)

        for key, value in data.items():
          if key == 'Creature List' and isinstance(value, dict) and 'value' in value:                        
            for creature in value:
              if 'FactionID' in creature:
                 creature['FactionID']['value'] += 46
                 print(filename)
                 print(creature)
                 print(creature['FactionID']['value']
                
                 with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
                    print(f"Modified {filename}")
      except (json.JSONDecodeError, FileNotFoundError) as e:
        print(f"Error processing {filename}: {e}")              


I have tried getting the FactionID 'value' integer using e.g. print(data['Creature List']['value']['FactionID']['value']), but this throws errors.
I'm not hugely experienced with python, any help appreciated. Thanks

please provide a minimal example and expected result. Without a small example we cannot provide you the help, i.e. we cannot demonstrate how it can be done and you cannot demonstrate what exactly fails.

value appears to be a list of dictionaries, so you'll have to specify WHICH entry in that list you are interested in getting the FactionID from. print(data['Creature List']['value'][0]['FactionID']['value']) for instance, to get the first Creature List value entry. It would be helpful if you could trim that JSON down into something that we can parse locally, and trim your code down to just your json.load and print() so we have a starting point to replicate locally.

Thanks JNevill. I had actually already tried print(data['Creature List']['value'][0]['FactionID']['value']. It comes up with a compile error - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.
I will edit the OP now to cut things down, thanks.

First of all, there's no need to iterate over all of the top-level keys in the json data. You only want the "Creature List" key, so just access it directly:
data["Creature List"]

Inside of that, you know you're looking for the "value" key, so you can access that directly also:
data["Creature List"]["data"]

This is a list of items, so you need to iterate over it:
for item in data["Creature List"]["data"]:

Then for each item you find, you're looking for the "FactionID" key, and then the "value" key inside of that.
So putting it all together, I think this is what you want:
for item in data["Creature List"]["data"]:
    item["FactionID"]["value"] += 7


Wonderful. This works like a charm. Thank you!

Hah, for some reason the script (as well as now correctly updating the 'FactionID' integers) is modifying certain other strings in the json. The strings are as follows:
"value": 9.5367431640625e-006
...which it is changing to
"value": 9.5367431640625e-06
[i.e. it's just stripping out one of the '0's from the '006']
..any idea why it's doing that and if I can make it stop, by any chance?

@ElGrillo any idea why it's doing that Not without seeing the whole code and the actual json data file.

Of course - in case you have a moment to look, here's the code: https://pastebin.com/FYn1hJFP
And here's the json of a sample file (clean - before the script has been run on it): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GoZL0qugT96W-s4_PR1S7Smda9K92_Nf/view?usp=sharing

@ElGrillo -006 changing to -06 isn't really a change at all; those are the same number.  But standard scientific notation uses two digits, so when python writes the new json file, it is just using standard notation.  I don't know why the original file was using three digits.

@ElGrillo And as a side comment, the code to save the updated json file is inside the inner loop, so you're writing the new json file hundreds of times, once per each item in the for item in data["Creature List"]["value"] loop. You only need to save it once, after that loop is done.

Understood. Many thanks again.
